# Will I get punished for my father's deeds?

Tags: allah

My father introduced a family to one of my cousins for marriage. They got married. After the marriage problems began and my dad acted as if it wasn't his responsibility. That girl aborted her baby too. Now they're divorced. I know somehow they think it's my dad's fault. I know it's my dad's fault but that girl aborted her baby too and it might be one of the reasons for divorce. Now I am afraid if in future my marriage happens will it break like my cousin? Will I suffer because of my dad's mistake?

Comment: Check out this: https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/28217/37617. It might help you out.

Comment: Why is it your dad's fault? People get married and get divorced the people who introduced them are generally doing this considering it a good deed. People may be introduced for marriage but find out they don't fit and separate ... Your dad introduced them, but they toke the decision to get married they had every chance to say "no". This is a wrong way of thinking. Everything a person does it is his own deed, decision and responsability for which he/she will be accountable in this life and the hereafter (except for a few exceptions like people who are ill-minded).

Comment: In fact a few centuries ago it was very common to have been divorced and married multiple time even for women. It is nothing wrong to get a divorce or ask for khul'a. It  is legal act in Islam.

Answer (score 1):

Praise be to Allah,

An incident and mistake from someone else has nothing to do with the other person as long as they don’t approve of it. In your case, your cousins failure of marriage has nothing to do with your marriage. Your father’s mistake has nothing to do with you as long as one doesn’t approve of the mistake the other person did. The Qur’an mentions that no one shall bear the burden of others’s sins and each person is only responsible for what they do